# Matlab matrix number formatting is much too long (coefficients of symbolic values)

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

This should be quite simple but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere:

I have a 2x2 matrix, it is calculated by using adjoint/determinant.
The matrix that returns is stupid large.

```
 +-                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        -+ 
  |                                                       s + 6/5                                                                                                         4830385804397659                                                   | 
  |             --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------,           - -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  | 
  |              2   24700384724018671 s                                                                                                   /  2   24700384724018671 s                                                                     \  | 
  |             s  + ------------------- - 119336023372378697084501879995957/1584563250285286751870879006720              9007199254740992 | s  + ------------------- - 119336023372378697084501879995957/1584563250285286751870879006720 |  | 
  |                   1407374883553280                                                                                                     \       1407374883553280                                                                       /  | 
  |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          | 
  |                                                   6228340816450595                                                                                          s + 4602306972750947/281474976710656                                         | 
  |  - ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------,             --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------             | 
  |                   /  2   24700384724018671 s                                                                     \               2   24700384724018671 s                                                                                 | 
  |    35184372088832 | s  + ------------------- - 119336023372378697084501879995957/1584563250285286751870879006720 |              s  + ------------------- - 119336023372378697084501879995957/1584563250285286751870879006720             | 
  |                   \       1407374883553280                                                                       /                    1407374883553280                                                                                   | 
  +-                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        -+
```

I would like to shorten the cells up a bit so that, say s*1.7551e+01.

Yes, s is symbolic, I would like to evaluate the coefficients or at least express them in scientific notation.  I have tried `format short e` and `ad./detr` with no luck.

Thank you in advance

Comment: The function I was looking for was `vpa()`

Usage in this case: `vpa(ad./detr)`

Answer (score 0):

The function I was looking for was `vpa()`

Usage in this case: `vpa(ad./detr)` now gives:

```
 +-                                                                                                                                                                -+ 
  |                                     s + 1.2                                                             0.53628055378647887518894776803791                       | 
  |   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------,  - ----------------------------------------------------------------------------  | 
  |    2                                                                                2                                                                            | 
  |   s  + 17.550678936131213703220055322163 s - 75.311618738408384768789333762935     s  + 17.550678936131213703220055322163 s - 75.311618738408384768789333762935  | 
  |                                                                                                                                                                  | 
  |                          177.0200929186840710372052853927                                            s + 16.350678936131213703220055322163                       | 
  |  - ----------------------------------------------------------------------------,  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------   | 
  |     2                                                                              2                                                                             | 
  |    s  + 17.550678936131213703220055322163 s - 75.311618738408384768789333762935   s  + 17.550678936131213703220055322163 s - 75.311618738408384768789333762935   | 
  +-                                                                                                                                                                -+
>>
```